# Javascript Arrays - Ensuring each batch has a certain element

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

I have an email script that reads in emails from a database and collects them into one huge object. Now these emails can be BCC, CC, TO type emails which must be passed to our email provider via an API in their respective type.

Their API allows batches up to 1000 emails which isn't the issue. The issue is that in each batch I have to have one TO address at least. In other words say by chance a batch has 1000 'BCC' type emails in it and not one 'TO' type email addresses. Those 1000 emails will not get sent. When you are dealing with 20,000 emails there are 20 batches created and there could very well be a batch that has all BCC or CC type emails with none of them being a TO type address.

So my question is how can I assure a TO address is in each batch during processing?

Some code along with the current output is below.

```
 while (addresses.length > 0) {

     // I do some processing here. The addresses above is a map of emails that
     // Something like: [ { label: 'to', address: 'jay@someaddress.com' } ]. 

     // Then the processing removes the individual labels from each email and slams
     // them into one key value for each email type using a filter function. We also
     // append some other things that must be separated as well like the recipient
     // variables. The sent information looks like this to our email provider. 
     {
         from: 'jay99@someaddress.com',
         subject: 'fff',
         text: 'fff',
         to: ['jay+3@someaddress.com', 'jay+8@someadd.com'],
         bcc: [],
         * * // WHAT happens here if all the email addresses reside here and none above in the 'TO' label? The email will fail. The code must ensure at least one 'TO' type address in each batch of 1000.**
         cc: [],
         'recipient-variables': {
             'jay+3@someaddress.com': {},
             'jay+8@someadd.com': {}
         }
     }

 }
```

My initial thought was to randomize it some how but wasn't sure how to do that. I think you almost have to do something to the initial array before it even gets into putting the emails into the right slots (IE type of emails). Suggestions? And thank you for taking the time to read my question. :)

Comment: Are you sure you need a real `TO`? Thunderbird lets me send mails with BCC only, for example, and when I check the source I see that it's internally sent with a `To: undisclosed_recipients: ;` header.

Comment: Yes. I brought this specific question up to them and they said with their system it will not send without the TO type having at least one address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomizing the combinations will not solve your problem either, since it does in no way guarantee that there is a 'to' recipient in all of your batches.

One way to solve this issue would be to create to buckets of recipients, one with all 'to' recipients, and another one with all others. This shouldn't be too hard, given that you have the complete list of addresses.

Then always take one 'to' address and 999 other addresses, package them into a batch and send them off. Repeat until either one of the buckets is empty. If the others bucket is empty first, only take the remaining 'to' recipients and send off the email until they are all gone as well.

If your 'to' bucket is empty first, you will have to come up with a different solution. Maybe make up dummy recipients?

Comment: Thanks TimoSta. We did the bucket thing and we also opened a ticket with the provider about the scenario that you brought up.